# ¿Dónde se guardan las redirecciones de joomla?

Tags: mysql, joomla3

Me gustaría saber en que parte de la base de datos se guardan las redirecciones, del componente redirect de joomla 3.2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La tabla de la base de datos se llama `{prefijo}_redirect_links`.

El prefijo fue el que se definió en la instalación al momento de instalar Joomla!

Los campos de esta tabla son:

```
id, old_url, new_url, referer, comment, hits, published, created_date, modified_date, header
```